# Why can't I change the printing type of blanket purchase orders on netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I'm attempting to create a custom advanced PDF for blanket purchase orders, yet when I go to the blanket purchase order's transaction form I can't change the printing type to be advanced. Is there  any way I can do this? Below is a screenshot of the blanket purchase order's transaction form after clicking "customize"

[image: Netsuite Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but it is likely because a blanket purchase order isn't meant to be seen by a customer. When you use the blanket purchase order feature you will still create real Purchase Orders when the Blanket PO is activated. You should be able to set the form for those and so make use of the Advanced HTML/PDF forms for the actual POs.

If you need to send one over (e.g. for approval) the records are fully scriptable which means you can create your own 'Print' button that triggers a Suitetlet to print the Blanket PO using a BFO template.